# GCS Dataflow throws an error - FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory found)

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, google-cloud-search

I have created a dataflow job in GCS which reads .tsv files from GCS Bucket and inserts into BigQuery Tables. Before forming a table row, I have to read a lookup file which has the column names.
This lookup file is inside .tar.gz directory along with other files but I need to read only the lookup files with the name column_headers.tsv

I have used a FileIO.match().filepattern() to read a list of file names from the .tar.gz directory but dataflow in GCS is throwing error stating FileNotFoundException

Below is the stack trace,

```
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: fs:/xxx_xxxx_xxxxx/initial_load/xxxxxxxx_2022-10-11-lookup_data.tar.gz (No such file or directory)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:187)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:108)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:56)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:39)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:121)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:117)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:218)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:169)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:83)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:420)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:389)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:314)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:140)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:120)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
     java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: gs:/crs_user_events/initial_load/napaonlineglobal_2022-10-11-lookup_data.tar.gz (No such file or directory)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    gradle_inital_load.ReadTarDir$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:411)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$ReadMatches$ToReadableFileFn.process(FileIO.java:874)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$ReadMatches$ToReadableFileFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:76)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:411)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1.processElement(ReshuffleOverrideFactory.java:86)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:185)
    ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:      fs:/xxx_xxxx_xxxx/initial_load/xxxxxx_2022-10-11-lookup_data.tar.gz (No such file or directory)
        java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
       java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    
    xxxx_inital_load.ReadFilexxxx.processElement(ReadFilexxxx.java:97)
"
timestamp: "2022-12-13T17:31:06.310507157Z"
}
```

[Dataflow steps fails](https://i.stack.imgum/vSVut.png)

My pipeline code is as below,

```
  package xxxx_inital_load;

 import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
 import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Compression;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO.ReadableFile;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.MatchResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResolveOptions.StandardResolveOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResourceId;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableDestination;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions.DirectRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn.ProcessContext;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn.ProcessElement;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionView;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TypeDescriptors;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.ValueInSingleWindow;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.annotations.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;

public class ReadFilexxxx {

     private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadFilexxxx.class);
     static String outputTableProject = "xxx-x-xxxx";
    static String outputTableDataset = "xxxx_events";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DataflowPipelineOptions dfOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(MyOptions.class);
        
        dfOptions.setProject("xxx-x-xxxx");
        dfOptions.setStagingLocation("fs://xxxx_events/xxxx");
        dfOptions.setRegion("us-eastx");
        dfOptions.setTempLocation("fs://xxxx_events/xxxx");
        dfOptions.setServiceAccount("xxxx-xx@xxx-x-xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.com");
        dfOptions.setSubnetwork(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx-xxx-x-xxxx-xxx/regions/us-eastx/subnetworks/x-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
        dfOptions.setUsePublicIps(false);

        dfOptions.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);

        DataflowRunner.fromOptions(dfOptions);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(dfOptions);

        // PCollection<String[]> fileContents =
        PCollectionView<String[]> filecontents = (PCollectionView<String[]>) p
                 
                .apply("MatchFile(s)", FileIO.match().filepattern(
                        "fs://xxxx_events/initial_load/*.tar.gz"))
                .apply("GCS File Match", FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(Compression.AUTO))
                .apply("Untar and read files", ParDo.of(new DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, String[]>() {
                //.apply("Untar and read files", ParDo.of(new DoFn<MatchResult.Metadata, String[]>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
                        String line = null;
                        String tmp = null;
                        String[] Data = null;// = new ArrayList<>();
                        String filename = c.element().getMetadata().resourceId().getFilename();
                        filename = "fs://xxxxx_events/initial_load/".concat(filename);
                        LOG.info("columns file path:", filename);
                        TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(
                                new GzipCompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
                        
                        TarArchiveEntry currentEntry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry();
                        BufferedReader br = null;
                        while (currentEntry != null) {
                            if (currentEntry.getName().contains("column_headers.tsv")) {
                                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tarInput)); // Read directly from tarInput
                                System.out.println("For File = " + currentEntry.getName());
                                while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                    line = tmp;
                                    Data = line.split("\t");
                                    System.out.println("line=" + line);
                                }
                                // br.close();
                            }
                            currentEntry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry(); // You forgot to iterate to the next file
                        }
                        br.close();
                        tarInput.close();
                        c.output(Data);
                    }
                })).apply(View.asSingleton());

        PCollection<String> lines = p.apply("Read Files",
                TextIO.read().from("fs://xxxx_events/initial_load/*.tsv.gz")
                        .withCompression(Compression.GZIP));

        p.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(ReadTarDir.class, TableAndRowCoder.of());

        PCollection<TableAndRow> tablerows = lines
                .apply("Transform File lines into TableAndRow", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableAndRow>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        int tabnam_idx, indx;
                        TableAndRow tbObj;
                        String tabName = null;
                        TableRow row = new TableRow();
                        String[] columns = c.sideInput(filecontents);
                        String[] arr = c.element().split("\t");

                        if (arr.length > 0) {

                            tabnam_idx = getIndex(columns, "channel");
                            indx = getIndex(columns, "page_event");

                            // ProductDetails
                            if ((arr[tabnam_idx].toString()).contains("productdetails")) {
                                tabName = "outputTableProject".concat(":").concat(outputTableDataset).concat(".")
                                        .concat("detail_page_view_events_idl");
                                // tabName = String.format("%s:%s.%s", outputTableProject,
                                // outputTableDataset,"Detail_Page_View_Events");
                                row.set("eventType", "detail-page-view");
                                int index = getIndex(columns, "evar6");
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != "") {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "mcvisid")]);
                                }
                                row.set("eventTime", arr[getIndex(columns, "date_time")]);
                                row.set("experimentIds", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar104")]);
                                row.set("productDetails.product.id", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);
                                row.set("userInfo.userId", "1");
                                row.set("userInfo.ipAddress", arr[getIndex(columns, "ip")]);
                                row.set("userInfo.userAgent", arr[getIndex(columns, "user_agent")]);
                                row.set("userInfo.directUserRequest", "1");
                                row.set("uri", arr[getIndex(columns, "page_url")]);
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "visit_referrer")] == "") {
                                    row.set("referrerUri", "1");
                                } else {
                                    row.set("referrerUri", arr[getIndex(columns, "visit_referrer")]);
                                }
                            }

                            // Homepage
                            
if ((arr[tabnam_idx].toString()).contains("homepage1")) {
                                tabName = "outputTableProject".concat(":").concat(outputTableDataset).concat(".")
                                        .concat("home_page_view_events_idl");
                                // tabName = String.format("%s:%s.%s", outputTableProject,
                                // outputTableDataset,"Home_Page_View_Events");
                                row.set("eventType", "home-page-view");
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != " ") {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "mcvisid")]);
                                }

                            }

                            // Search
                            indx = getIndex(columns, "page_event");
                            if ((arr[tabnam_idx].toString()).contains("search") && arr[indx] == "0") {
                                tabName = "outputTableProject".concat(":").concat(outputTableDataset).concat(".")
                                        .concat("search_events_idl");
                                // tabName = String.format("%s:%s.%s", outputTableProject,
                                // outputTableDataset,"Pass Table Name here");
                                /* create row here */
                                row.set("eventType", "search");
                            if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != " ") {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "mcvisid")]);
                                }
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != " ") {
                                    row.set("searchQuery", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar1")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("searchQuery", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar2")]);
                                }
                                row.set("productDetails.product.id", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);

                            }

                            // Browse
                            indx = getIndex(columns, "page_event");
                            if ((arr[tabnam_idx].toString()).contains("category-landing") && arr[indx] == "0") {
                                tabName = "outputTableProject".concat(":").concat(outputTableDataset).concat(".")
                                        .concat("category_page_view_events_idl");
                                /* create row here */
                                row.set("eventType", "category-page-view");
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != " ") {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "mcvisid")]);
                                }
                                row.set("pageCategories", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar104")]);
                                }

                            // add-to-cart
                            if (arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")] != null && arr[indx] == "12") {
                                tabName = "outputTableProject".concat(":").concat(outputTableDataset).concat(".")
                                        .concat("add_to_cart_events_idl");
                                /* create row here */
                                row.set("eventType", "add-to-cart");
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != " ") {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "mcvisid")]);
                                }
                                row.set("productDetails.product.id", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);   
                            }

                            // purchase complete
                            indx = getIndex(columns, "page_event");
                            if (arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")] != null && arr[indx] == "1") {
                                tabName = "outputTableProject".concat(":").concat(outputTableDataset).concat(".")
                                        .concat("purchase_complete_events_idl");
                                
                                
/* create row here */
                                row.set("eventType", "home-page-view");
                                if (arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")] != " ") {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "evar6")]);
                                } else {
                                    row.set("visitorId", arr[getIndex(columns, "mcvisid")]);
                                }
                                row.set("productDetails.product.id", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);
                                row.set("productDetails.product.quantity", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);
                                row.set("purchaseTransaction.revenue", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);
                                row.set("purchaseTransaction.currencyCode", arr[getIndex(columns, "product_list")]);
                            }
                                
                            }

                        
                LOG.info("Row:" + row.toString());
                tbObj = new TableAndRow(row, tabName);
                c.output(tbObj);

                    }
            }).withSideInputs(filecontents)).setCoder(TableAndRowCoder.of());

    tablerows.apply("Write to BigQuery",
            BigQueryIO.<TableAndRow>write().to(line -> getTableName(line))
                    .withFormatFunction((TableAndRow line) -> convertToTableRow(line))
                         .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                         .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

         p.run().waitUntilFinish();
         System.out.println("Pipeline Executed");
    }

     private static TableRow convertToTableRow(TableAndRow line) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TableRow row = line.getRow();
        return row;
    }

    public static int getIndex(String[] Data, String str) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < Data.length; j++) {
            if (Data[j].contains(str)) {
                index = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    public static TableDestination getTableName(ValueInSingleWindow<TableAndRow> line) {

        TableDestination destination;
        TableAndRow row = line.getValue();

        destination = new TableDestination(row.getTab_name(), null);

        return destination;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that you're sending a GCS path into Java's `FileInputStream` which isn't aware of GCS and doesn't know what to do with `gs://` paths. Your `element` in this case is a Beam [ReadableFile](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.ReadableFile.html#open--). The methods of that class such as `open` and `readFullyAsBytes` *are* aware of GCS and can make appropriate calls under the hood.

Your line above for creating the `TarArchiveInputStream` would look something like the following:

```
import java.nio.channels.Channels;

TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = 
  new TarArchiveInputStream(
    new GzipCompressorInputStream(
      Channels.newInputStream(c.element.open())));
```

Alternatively, you can see an example of using Beam constructs to read a file based on a string path (which could be a GCS path) in https://github.com/mozilla/gcp-ingestion/blob/main/ingestion-beam/src/main/java/com/mozilla/telemetry/util/BeamFileInputStream.java

Comment: Can you please share any sample code if you have as i am new to DataFlow Pipeline

Comment: I updated my answer to include a rough code snippet and a link to an example in Mozilla's telemetry pipeline codebase.